# INT Data type for datetime objects

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw some developers using INT(11) as data type for datetime objects.
I always using `DATETIME` data type.
Is there advantage/disadvantage to using INT for datetime objects?

In Yii frame, there is a table `tbl_migrate` which contains such type field.

Comment: Well i think use the type makes the most sense to the tier where you do your data processing.

Comment: Advantage - timestamps are in UTC. Disadvantage - when you look at the integers directly you have no clue what the date they display unless you format it. Datetime - no implied timezone associated with it, you have to take care of it yourself. Advantage - well, the date is formatted and you can easily understand it, there's plethora of functions for offsetting the dates in MySQL / PHP.

Comment: I think in MySQL is 4 byte and DATETIME is 8 byte.

Comment: Internally, datetime takes 8 bytes to store the information. However, there are various integer sizes that MySQL can use so using space as an excuse to use one format and not another is bad and mostly stupid reason.

Comment: @N.B. I couldn't get your point. I think MySQL always use 4 bytes for INT type. How MySQL will use various sizes for INT type?

Comment: TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INT, BIGINT - different integer sizes. But that's not the "issue", there are internal functions of each storage engine that can allocate more physical space or not deallocate it when deletion occurs etc. Basically, choosing one type of data over another because of storage requirements is generally a sign of having a bad idea.

Comment: @N.B. Still I am not getting your point. Here I am using INT without any prefix(like TINY,SMALL). I don't think considering storage requirement is bad idea. If I want store a date of form YYY-MM-DD, I should use DATE instead of DATETIME. Such situation we should consider storage requirements.

Comment: Yes, you are correct for that case. But, choosing INT over DATETIME because DATETIME uses 8 bytes is a bad decision, IF you need the data in DATETIME format.

Comment: @N.B. Yes, you are also correct for that case :) Changing the data type just for the sake of storage space.